# What's the URI to play any video that i have been uploaded on wowza server?

Tags: video-streaming, playback, wowza

I'm very new to Wowza. Just installed and configured an Wowza server. After this was able to play sample.mp4. Then I uploaded an video to server and was able to see ad play it in admin web interface.

But how can I use that video on my site. I'm using FlowPlayer and I need an URI.

Comment: https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-use-flowplayer-with-wowza-media-server-software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the default storage directory in wowza is wowza_home/content. You can change this setting in conf/vod/Application.xml

so for example you upload abc.mp4 video inside "content" directory then
RTMP playback url will be:
rtmp://wowzaip:1935/vod/mp4:abc.mp4

HLS (for iphone and android) playback will be:
http://wowzaip:1935/vod/mp4:sample.mp4/playlist.m3u8

Comment: link dead ? what does it mean ?

Comment: thank you for your answer, it helped me a lot. But what would be a HTTP url ?